# Backup SonarQube Quality Gates

Tags: sonarqube

We are in the process of moving our SonarQube server and DB on to AWS and I want to be able to copy the setting and configuration from the existing server to the new one in AWS.  The quality profiles have a back up operation, so these are easy to move.  Is there something similar for the quality gates?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. Your best bet here is pen and paper. :-/

Comment: Is this still true? No way to copy off the filesystem either?

Comment: Yes, its still true

Comment: Surely this still cannot be true? @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: Yep. Still true @Nanotron.

Comment: @Nanotron, Yes it is true. And don't call me Shirley

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround I found [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5766).
This issue was closed for lack of traction but it suggests the API workaround for importing and exporting the quality gates.

[API](https://github.com/AssafKatz3/SonarQube_Settings_Over_GIT)